# What about the physical contruction or circuit layout of 1GHz+ ADC's make them expensive?

Tags: adc

I was looking through a list of 1GHz ADC's on a [suppliers site](http://www.analog.com/en/parametricsearch/10826#/p1746=1000000000%7C26000000000), they ranged from 300$-1000$ USD which is quite expensive an limits the amount of products they can be used in. (I've never designed with anything beyond 1MSPS, someday it might be fun for a hobby project to design a superfast USB oscilloscope or something)

What about their physical construction or circuit makes them so expensive? It couldn't be the package because there are comparable parts in the same package that are in the 10$ range.

Comment: Well I don't think I have the knowledge to tell you anything you don't know about why.  I'm sure you noticed it's fast and has a lot going on in it.  I'm curious too because it seems like something that would ship in enough volume to be cheap.  I just wanted to add that the cheapest one on your list,  AD9690 is $4809.71 USD per cubic centimeter, plus shipping.  Hmm...  Maybe I shouldn't mix USD with non-freedom units.  $788170.57 per cubic inch.

Comment: DSO's cost range are usually in $k/ Gsps because analog and high-quality Gallium Arsenide high-speed logic is expensive to make.

Comment: I'm surprised you'd even have to ask. Designing a monotonic GHz A/D or D/A is an incredible challenge. The laws of supply and demand would set the price high. If you look at the power used and the core voltages you can see that it's probably mostly ECL internally, and at the desired frequencies a microwave engineering task.

Comment: They are ultra-expensive in the same way that GHZ FPGA's are. Time skewing and parasitic capacitance make them feasible only because generations of software now do most of the layout. High end O-scopes go to 100 GHZ, not including the nitrogen cooling tanks.

Comment: I am flagging this as too broad in scope for simple answers or even many answers. VTC.

Comment: if it were 12 nm CMOS , can you imagine how hard it is to fabricate the high temperature and voltage gas epitaxial layers without creating ESD damage and still have 0.001% tolerance on circuits

Comment: I'd say, supply and demand + development and manufacturing costs. Higher-run chips can drop in price because tens of thousands are being made monthly... not so on specialty chips.

Comment: @laptop Increase the demand and add 1k units to your Digikey cart and ask for a discount on the ADC12D1800RFIUT since $472,317.00 is just over your buying limit of $400k

Comment: So so far we have special Ga-As fabrication and design challenge, specialized specialist may be required(microwave engineer), supply and demand (this one surprised me, but I guess 1ghz adc is not necessary in most cases).  Also it sounds like if you're using cmos you'd be chucking a lot of wafers.  Is this really a task that, say a 2GHz dedicated CPU couldn't perform?

Comment: Yes There is quite a difference to Analog high speed design fabrication than logic.

Comment: HMCAD1511 is the adc in a lot of lost cost 1GSa scopes, like the ds1054z 1 off price is under 100 from a distributor

Comment: Some highspeed ADCs have the errors characterized, and then corrected in a lookup table.

Comment: @Jack I've never downloaded a super high speed ADC datasheet, and never designed with one, I usually operate on the other end of the spectrum towards DC and make measurements in the nV to pV range